# Complément du nom sans préposition ?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, usage, prépositions, de

On peut souvent rencontrer des expressions où un nom est complété par un groupe nominal sans préposition. Très souvent, il s'agit d'un nom propre (par ex. *Rue **la Fayette***, *Centre **Didot***), mais apparemment, en général, il peut s'agir de n'importe quel groupe nominal, par ex. *formulaire **admission***, *liste **pièces à fournir*** etc. Il me semble que cette construction essentiellement remplace un complément du nom avec « de ».

Dans quels contextes peut-on utiliser cette construction ? Est-ce qu'on peut simplement omettre la préposition « de » de tout complément du nom ? (Pouvez-vous donner des exemples où cela ne fonctionne pas ?) S'agit-il du français standard, ou est-ce plutôt un raccourci informel ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Ça fonctionne

Pour introduction du nom d'un lieu *(immeuble, rue, parc, montagne, cours ou étendues d’eau<sup>1</sup>)*, voire d'une raison sociale introduite par exemple par le type de négoce qu'on y fait ou de service qu'on y offre *(poissonnerie Ordralphabétix, remorquage Picard)*, le processus est des plus communs. On pourrait même dans une certaine mesure introduire d'autres items nommés de cette manière *(ici un écrit et un prix littéraire)* :

> Son roman ***La vie devant soi*** lui a valu un second prix ***Goncourt***.

Pour des listes et formulaires, ces raccourcis sont sans doute communs dans la langue orale commerciale *(où tout tend à se raccourcir)* ou bureaucratique/légale *(où les titres sont parfois longs et compliqués)*, en plus des exemples d'étiquetage mentionnés dans [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/31631/13100) et probablement aussi des noms des fichiers électroniques contenant lesdits documents.

Dans la langue informatique, les exemples sont aussi assez nombreux. On pourrait penser au *compte d’utilisateur*, souvent raccourci à un plus simple et peu ambigu *compte utilisateur*.

Dans le domaine de l'éducation, du moins au Québec, il est courant d'entendre une construction comme *« je suis un programme alternance travail-études »*. On pourra contester la première introduction *(programme alternance)* comme relevant d'une langue un peu relâchée, mais la seconde *(alternance travail-études)* est bien selon moi la forme correcte, sans **de**.

---

#### Ça marche beaucoup moins bien

Il existe sûrement de nombreux cas où ce genre de raccourci sonnerait plus bizarre, tout au moins dans certains contextes... Par exemple lorsque la fonction, la source, la nature ou le détail plutôt que la dénomination sont introduits.

Il me vient à l'esprit :

- *Dictionnaire synonymes et antonymes* sonne très mal.
- *L'eau **d**'écoulement fluvial*, jamais *l'eau écoulement fluvial*
- *Un cas **de** récidive* → je ne crois pas avoir entendu *un cas récidive*.
- On accepterait peut-être d'être ***un marchand de bric-à-brac***, mais probablement pas d'être **un marchand bric-à-brac...**

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Deux cas qui contrastent : dans le centre nord du Canada se trouvent deux grandes mers, dont l’une n’est qu’une protubérance de l’autre : la **baie James** et la **baie d’Hudson**. La baie James est parfois, mais rarement, identifiée comme la baie **de** James. La baie d’Hudson, elle, ne perd jamais son **d’** (peut-être pour éviter le hiatus ?).</sub>

Answer (score 5):

Dans le cadre de noms de lieux ou rues, cela passe comme une lettre à la poste. Les 2 exemples que vous donnez avec des noms communs sont effectivement plus à considérer comme un raccourci plutôt informel. 
Par exemple, j'imagine facilement un hopital où les formulaires d'admission sont titrés "Formulaire d'admission" mais rangés dans un dossier étiqueté "Formulaires admission". Pareil pour un formulaire de "Demande de dédommagement pour accident de travail"/"Dédommagement accident travail", etc...

Il doit certainement y avoir des exemple où ça fonctionne moins bien voire pas du tout mais j'avoue que là comme ça je n'en trouve pas.

Comment: Un commentaire hors-sujet au cas où : *farde* se dit dossier ou chemise en France.

Comment: Je n'avais pas conscience qu'il s'agissait d'un belgicisme. J'essaie d'éviter ceux-ci sur ce site, j'ai donc édité ma réponse en conséquence... Merci de la précision !

Comment: Quelques belgicismes/helvétismes mériteraient d'être adoptés par l'ensemble de la francophonie, en particulier *septante*, *nonante* et le *huitante* vaudois...