# Qu'est-ce qu'un « substantif actualisé » et à quoi sert cette classification ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, vocabulaire, dictionnaires

Dans un [dictionnaire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0/0) on parle plusieurs fois de substantif *[actualisé](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/actualis%C3%A9), pas/non actualisé*. Est-ce relié à l'idée de « Poser comme probable ou effective, c'est-à-dire actuelle (p. oppos. à virtuelle) une idée préalablement examinée par la pensée [...] » (TLFi) et comment s'appliquerait cette notion à des substantifs dans un article sur la préposition *à* et qu'elle en serait l'utilité/la fonction ?

Comment: J'ai failli de ne pas poster [cette reponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/34301/why-is-the-%C3%A0-used-in-the-sentence-les-poissons-sont-des-animaux-%C3%A0-sang-froi/34324#34324) justement car je ne connaissais pas ce terme-la! Je ne le connais toujours pas assez bien pour repondre ici, mais je crois que la reponse se trouve parmi les mots de [ce livre](https://books.google.com/books?id=lskaSr4WCFQC&pg=PA27&dq=%22substantif+non-actualise%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji27-m2IzhAhXIhOAKHX3EAIIQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22substantif%20non-actualise%22&f=false) dont j'en pige que dalle!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Un substantif isolé est abstrait. Il gagne sa substance quand il est actualisé. L'actualisation est souvent réalisée par l'utilisation d'un article.

***Chapeau*** n'est pas actualisé au début de cette phrase, mais le devient quand on parle d'un **chapeau**, du **chapeau**, de trois **chapeaux**...

Dans l'article sur la préposition ***à***, on trouve des substantifs non actualisés dans les expression :

> être à charge
>
> être à poil
>
> boite à lettres

que l'on retrouve actualisés dans :

> être à la charge
>
> être au poil
>
> boite aux lettres

Dans le premier groupe, la charge, le poil ou les lettres ne sont pas actualisés, la charge reste à prouver, on ne désigne pas de poil en particulier, la boite à lettre est conçue pour en recevoir.

Dans le deuxième groupe, la charge, le poil et les lettres sont actualisés, existent.

Quelqu'un ou quelque chose est *à **la** charge* de quelqu'un, *c'est au poil* signifie être aussi près de la perfection que le diamètre d'**un** poil peut l'être, une *boite aux lettres* contient des lettres (c'est donc un usage impropre).

L'utilité de cette classification est simplement de permettre de distinguer des nuances de sens et d'usage, un dictionnaire comme le TLFi ayant pour vocation d'être exhaustif et détaillé.

De la hiérarchie décrite dans l'entrée du mot étudié, ici *à*, on peut extraire par exemple les indications suivantes :

> **D.−** Le substantif déterminé par le complément introduit par à est un substantif de sens concret (désignant des êtres inanimés ou des animaux)
> ...
> **3.** À introduit un compl. d'accompagnement.− À signifie « avec », « qui a »
> **a)** À + subst. non actualisé
> **b)** À + subst. actualisé
> ...
> **4.** À introduit un compl. de manière.− À signifie « qui est à »
> **a)** À + subst. non actualisé

à partir desquelles il est plus facile de distinguer les nuances entre :

> **D.- 3. a)** homme à femme
>
> **D.- 3. b)** homme à l'oreille cassée
>
> **D.- 4. a)** homme à cheval

Comment: Oui, *à poil* est un peu tiré par les cheveux, d'autant plus qu'un bébé qui vient de naître est à poil bien qu'en étant dépourvu... Avec la boite à/aux lettres, les deux formes sont en concurrence pour désigner le même objet. On peut aussi comparer un *animal à sang chaud* et un *homme au sang chaud*.