# What does the à mean here?

Tags: sens, à

I'm reading *Une Araignée Malavisée* by Pierre Béarn. The first line is a bit confusing to me:

> Une fleur au pistil prudent

as *au* = *à le*, what does the *à* mean here?

It seems it means "with", but I didn't see this usage before.

For example, on [WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/%C3%A0) , *à* only listed as "at", "to", "in" or "until", no "with" meaning.

On my *Le Robert junior poche* dictionary, it lists out

1. Indique le lieu. *Il habite à Paris.*
2. Indique le moment. *Elle se lèva
   à sept heures.*
3. Indique l'appartenance . *Ce stylo est à Julie.*
4. Indiaue le moyen. *Léa se promène à bicyclette.*
5. *Un tasse à thé* est faite pour contenir du *thé*.
6. Introduit un complément indirect. *Louise plaît à tout le monde.*

, also no meaning of "with".

The full content of the poem is as below

> Une Araignée Malavisée
>
> Pierre Béarn
>
> Une fleur au pistil prudent
> qui se voulait incorruptible
> ne s'ouvrait vraiment que la nuit
> quand les abeilles sont au nid.
>
> Lors , une araignée survenant
> tira sur elle un toit de rêve
> pour mieux capturer les abeilles
> dont le vol serait étourdi.
>
> Mais au matin, mal réveillée,
> la fleur enferma l'araignée.
>
> Ça t'apprendra petite idiote
> à ne pas te surestimer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means *with*, as you suspected.

I think the problem is that you need to use a larger dictionary.

In the [*online*](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/a) (which is not the Junior pocket version) *Robert*, they have the definition: "Accompagnement. ➙ avec. *Un pain aux raisins.*"

In the [Collins French-English dictionary,](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/french-english/%C3%A0) they have the definition *"(caractérisation, manière)*
l’homme aux yeux bleus  the man with the blue eyes," which is a very good match to the use you're wondering about.

And in your [word-reference](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/%C3%A0) link, they give:
"à, au, aux prép    (avec) (feature, clothing)  with prep. (clothing)   in prep.
L'homme au chapeau m'a regardé toute la soirée.
The man with the hat was watching me all evening.
The man in the hat was watching me all evening."

The pistil is a feature of the flower, so this is the relevant definition.

Why did they take this case out of *la version Junior poche*? Presumably to save space, but to me it seems like a common enough usage that they should have left it. Usually, *with* should be translated by *avec*, but *à* is better in cases like this.

And for another example of this usage, *The Man with the Golden Gun* (the James Bond film) is *L'Homme au pistolet d'or* in French.

Comment: Another way to rephrase *Une fleur au pistil prudent* in French is *Une fleur dont le pistil était prudent*.

Answer (score 2):

*À* introduit un complément d'accompagnement [some type of adjectival prepositional phrase].− *À* signifie « avec », « qui a » ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0), III, D, 3, b), avec un substantif *actualisé* par l'article (*le*), tel qu'abordé indirectement [ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/34344).